# Событие клика по списку

Tags: reactjs

Являюсь новичком в react, стоит вопрос, как применить какие-либо действия к элементам (в данном случае со списком). Вот пример:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = { classToggle: '' }; 
    }

    handleClick() {
        const newClass = this.state.classToggle === '' ? 'active' : '';
        this.setState({ classToggle: newClass });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {arr.map(elem => <li className={this.state.classToggle} onClick={this.handleClick}>{elem}</li>)}
            </ul>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<List />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.active {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Я знаю, что ко всем элементам списка добавится класс. Вопрос, как сделать, чтобы класс добавлялся только к тому элементу по которому кликнули?
На js это делается просто, возьмем jquery:

```
  $('li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active');
  })
```

Возможно, я изучаю его неправильно, раз столь простая задача вызвала у меня трудности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например можно вынести `<li>` в отдельный компонент со своей независимой обработкой клика:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

class List extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return ( 
            <ul> {arr.map(elem => <LiElement> {elem} </LiElement>)} </ul>
        )
    }
}

class LiElement extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            classToggle: ''
        };
    }

    handleClick = () => {
        const newClass = this.state.classToggle === '' ? 'active' : '';
        this.setState({
            classToggle: newClass
        });
    };

    render() {
        return ( 
            <li 
                className = {this.state.classToggle}
                onClick = {this.handleClick} 
            > {this.props.children} </li>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render( < List / > , document.getElementById('app'));
```

```css
.active {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за решение)

Comment: А как сделать тоже самое только на функциональном компоненте, кто поможет?

Comment: @Marat, смотри [пример](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) в справке